# What is the correct way to add an event listener to the window in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a resize event listener to the browser window in a React component. I did it like that:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => this.handleWindowResized())
}
```

Is that a correct way of doing it in terms of good and bad practices in React, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will lead to a dangling handler when the component unmounts, because you are creating an anonymous function that you do not have a handle on which can be used to de-register the event listener when your React component is unmounted.

Unfortunately in JavaScript instance methods are not automatically bound to the instance, so you cannot pass reference to the instance method directly *unless* it has been bound explicitly to the instance. You can do this in the class constructor, and then use reference to the instance method directly during registration and de-registration of the event listener.

Using this approach, your event listener is only "active" for the lifetime of your React component.

Like so:

```
class Something extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleWindowResized = this.handleWindowResized.bind(this)
  }

  handleWindowResized() {
    console.log("window resized")
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleWindowResized)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleWindowResized)
  }
}
```